# How to authenticate against Spring Security from Android app?

Tags: java, android, authentication, spring-security

I'm building a WebApp using Spring. It is secured by Spring Security and should be accessed from an Android app too. In the web-version i'm using a basic login page.

To authenticate from Android i plan to just send an http request to the standard authentication url /j_spring_security_check with the credentials. And then allways send the cookie with every new request to stay authenticated.

Because the whole WebApp should only be accessed by logged in users, it is necessary to login at every startup of a Session. I tried to send the described Request via a simple html formular:

```
<html>
    <head><title>Test</title></head>
    <body>
        <form action="http://localhost:8080/livefeedback/j_spring_security_check" method="post">
            <input type="text", name="j_username" /><br />
            <input type="password" name="jpassword" /><br />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

For the sake of clarity: I want to send a http request from the android app similar to the one generated by sending this html form.

But I am just redirected to my standard login page. I think it's because I have to receive a session id from spring before attempting to login. And I'm not shure if there is a better way to login from the android app.

Here is my http configuration in spring-security.xml:

```
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login"
            access="permitAll"/>
        <access-denied-handler />
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/"/>
        <logout />
</http>
```

thanking you in anticipation for every hint!

Comment: did you check if you are logged in after you get forwarded to the login page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a (very) old web app, with Spring Security, that I log into from an Android app, both to do REST-ish calls and to scrape HTML.

I'm not sure if what I do will work for your app, but I find that with mine, the trick is to first request the page that you actually want to access.

I observed that when you do this while unauthenticated, that original destination is saved in session, and you then get redirected to the login page. 
In my case, it's actually a "login/prelogin" - this is almost certainly different for your app.

Once I have requested the page, and been redirected, I post the login parameters to the appropriate URL (you'll have to see where your login form posts to), and if the login is successful, I get a redirect for the original page that asked for.

Comment: Indeed I solved the problem that way. I first had to request any site from the web app in order to get a valid session id (the cookie). Afterwards I was able to log in by sending the credentials to the appropriate URL.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, apps are usually built to consume REST APIs. Because mobile apps don't run inside of web browsers, this should be the easiest and recommended approach. You can watch the lecture made by [Virgil Dobjanschi](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE) that works at google. Virgil explains in the very beginning the advantages of using REST APIs. REST APIs can be secured very easily with HTTP Basic. With just some few steps, Spring Security can be configured to secure REST APIs.

Comment: OP was asking how to log in to his existing web app, not how to change the web app to accommodate access by his Android app.